# Fourier transform magnitude filtering

Tags: python-3.x, filtering, fft, opencv3.0

I am trying to filter a fourier transform low intensity. I can get the correct image representation with the help of the examples provided. However, I am not sure how I can get the inverse transform to get the image back. dft_shift is a float32 (256,320,2). To get the magnitude spectrum, the example I used extract cv2.magnitude(dft_shift[:,:,0] and dft_shift[:,:,1] to calculate the log. I am not quite sure why np.log takes two input. magitude_spectrum is float32 (256,320) so I can't just do (see the code bellow for context):

```
f_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(mag_spec)
img_back = np.fft.ifft2(f_ishift)
img_back = np.abs(img_back)
```

Any suggestion? I am desperate at this point...

Here's the code and the result:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('G:\\Python\\Original\\frame13.jpg',0)  

dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(img),flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)
magnitude_spectrum = 20*np.log(cv2.magnitude(dft_shift[:,:,0],dft_shift[:,:,1]))

rows, cols = img.shape
mag_spec=20*np.log(cv2.magnitude(dft_shift[:,:,0],dft_shift[:,:,1]))
for i in range(0,rows-1):
    for j in range(0,cols-1):
        if mag_spec[i,j]<130:
            mag_spec[i,j]=0        

f_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(mag_spec)
img_back = np.fft.ifft2(f_ishift)
img_back = np.abs(img_back)
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(magnitude_spectrum, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Magnitude spectrum'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(mag_spec, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('With mask'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

[Plot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snhCO.png)

Answer (score 1):

I decided to proceed with the way the example did it. First make a mask of 0 and 1 then apply it to the (x,x,2) array.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('G:\\Python\\Original\\frame13.jpg',0)

#LPF montre deux images correspondant aux transformées de fourier modif (LPF) et pas modif
dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(img),flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)
magnitude_spectrum = 20*np.log(cv2.magnitude(dft_shift[:,:,0],dft_shift[:,:,1]))

rows, cols = img.shape
mask = np.zeros((rows,cols,2),np.uint8)
mag_spec=20*np.log(cv2.magnitude(dft_shift[:,:,0],dft_shift[:,:,1]))
for i in range(0,rows-1):
    for j in range(0,cols-1):
        if mag_spec[i,j]>100:
            mask[i,j]=1        
fshift=dft_shift*mask    
f_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(fshift)
img_back = cv2.idft(f_ishift)
img_back = cv2.magnitude(img_back[:,:,0],img_back[:,:,1])
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(magnitude_spectrum, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Magnitude spectrum'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img_back, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('With mask'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```